# Error: Your homepage is not available when Trusted Signer is disabled

Tags: parity

Just launched parity (using v.1.4.4 at the moment) as always, and when I try to access its UI (via http://localhost:8080/ ), I get this error:

```
404 Not Found
Your homepage is not available when Trusted Signer is disabled.

You can still access dapps by writing a correct address, though. Re-enable Signer to get your homepage back.
```

How can I reenable the signer? I've already tried `parity signer new-token` in the command line, and it gives me a new token, but I cannot do anything with that token in the 404 page, so I'm lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are not running with `--no-ui` flag.

Geth-compatibility mode (`--geth`) also disables the UI by default, if you wish to use UI together with Geth-compatibility run with `--geth --force-ui`.

Comment: running --force-ui worked, I dont run geth any idea why it didnt load by default ?